# Problema con proxy request

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy desarollando un bot telegram, para la empresa que trabajo, el problema es que no puedo tener respuesta de entrada ni salida, porque la conexión esta condicionada por proxy, pero desde navegadores si tengo acceso a internet.

Ya intente configurar la ip del proxy, junto al puerto y el usuario, pero esta condicionado el acceso solo a los navegadores.

Nota: La app Python debe estar ejecutándose en el servidor interno de la empresa, así que un servidor externo no es factible.

**Edición:**

Aquí esta un fragmento de código con el que intento hacer un request a un servidor externo:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import telebot
# import socket
import urllib.request

proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://USUARIO:PASS#@IP:PUERTO_CONEXIÓN'})
auth = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib.request.HTTPHandler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

conn = urllib.request.urlopen('http://telegram.org')
return_str = conn.read()

# Ponemos nuestro TOKEN generado con el @BotFather
TOKEN = 'TOKEN DEL BOT'
# Creamos nuestra instancia "mi_bot" a partir de ese TOKEN
mi_bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


def listener(*mensajes):   # #Cuando llega un mensaje se ejecuta esta función
    for m in mensajes:
        chat_id = m.chat.id
        if m.content_type == 'text':
            text = m.text
            mi_bot.send_message(ID_CHAT, "envio un mensaje al azar")
            mi_bot.send_message(ID_CHAT, text)


mi_bot.set_update_listener(listener)  # registrar la funcion listener
mi_bot.polling()

while True:  # No terminamos nuestro programa
    pass
```

El resultado:

```
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Autentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Acces to the Web proxy filter is denied. )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es raro.. .si te funciona el proxy en el navegador te debería funcionar...
¿La petición es por algun puerto no-estandar?

Como solucion instala un Proxy CNTLM (se graba la autenticacion usuario/clave/dominio) y luego apuntas el proxy de tu aplicacion al equipo que tenga el proxy CNTLM y saldrías de forma "transparente"...